# Css animation steps over vs cubic-bezier

Tags: css, animation, frame-rate

I'm using a css animation in my page which makes the element rotate on itself on Y axis:

```
@keyframes rotateony {
100% { 
  transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(-360deg) ;
  }
}
#testdiv {
animation: rotateony 2.4s infinite linear;
}
```

But my page is a little bit laggy on mobile and that's the only element animating and no background java is running. I'm trying to improve the whole page performance, I read that you need to target 60fps synchronicity, so I thought that by using

```
animation: rotateony 2.4s infinite steps(144); /*144 = 2.4*60 => 60fps) */
```

or

```
animation: rotateony 2.4s infinite steps(72); /*72 = 2.4*30 => 30fps */
```

I can force the browser to makes frames synchronous to the device refresh rate. 
Is this something that can really improve the performance? Visually, I can't tell the difference between all 3 of them. How can I improve this animations performance? I tried to test it using chrome inspet devices with my smartphone, but chrome debugger makes the page laggy by itself and does not give a good estimate of the real frame rate.